# Unauthorized Access exception when i try to create a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, directory

i have an exception `Unauthorized Access` when i did this :

```
if (fileurl != null && fileurl.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl.FileName);
                // var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName;
                 var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Projets", fileName);
                 fileurl.SaveAs(path);
                 string path2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);
```

I saved a compressed file `fileurl.SaveAs(path);` and i'd like o create a new directory in the same path. i verify the path `path2` and it is ok. but the instruction `Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);` failed and the exception of `Unauthorized Access` appears .

Why this happens ? how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you intend to create a directory (folder) which has the same name as a file (the one you just saved)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a permissions problem.  Make sure that your user has read/write file permissions.

Comment: No, make sure that the fileurl.SaveAs(path) has permissions to write.  try changing that file permission to 777, or the directory above

Comment: Okay, sure.  Mark me down for trying to help.  Now it's feeling more like StackExchange.

Comment: Okay. Accepted answer is just what I said.  Permission issue.  Thanks to the person that shouldn't be able to downvote.  Really love having you on stackexchange.

Comment: @Eric, I believe you did, though not as I answered more explicitly in more details. I did not down vote you, and I up voted you. My answer to other questions was down voted occasionally, and the guys generally would give the reasons. It might be good that giving reason why down voting is mandatory. BTW, this is another topic then you might want to raise to the product owner of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to set the path to C:\Projets or C:\Projects ?
You may get unauthorized access on a path that doesn't exist

Comment: @Lamloumi2 He's saying that you may have used the incorrect path.

Answer (score 0):

You tag this as ASP.NET so you can't do as console or windows form applications.

your web application run on server side  and with different user account.

You need to give permission to app pool running user and also since this is web application you need to write to directory under your web site or another virtual directory which accessible by the app pool user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the identity of the app pool running your web app. The default identify has not permission to C:\Projets and alike. You need to explicitly grand the user or the user group of the identity with permission of writing to C:\Projets.