# Error creating folder using ASP.NET code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a folder using the two methods below.

**Method 1**

```
if (directoryInfo.Exists)
{
    directoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory(ddlCat.SelectedItem.Text);
    Label1.Text = "Directory " + ddlCat.SelectedItem.Text + " Created";
}
```

**Method 2**

```
var folder = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + ddlCat.SelectedItem.Text);

if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}
```

Where ddlCat is a dropdownlist.

before executing the code, I modified the permission of the folder to Full for the current user. However, I'm still getting this error:

> UnauthorisedAccessException was unhandled by the user code Access to
>   the path 'Accessories' is denied.

The folder in which I'm creating subfolder is "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\UploadImages"

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Not this one again, hold on....

Comment: Access denied is usually access denied. Have you verified that the app pool account has the appropriate permissions to that directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.UnauthorizedAccessException while creating a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974590/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-creating-a-file)

Comment: Have you granted permission to the IIS user?

Comment: Or [Unauthorized Access exception when i try to create a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833482/unauthorized-access-exception-when-i-try-to-create-a-directory)

Comment: @marc Thanks marc your quick response solved my problem.. by default the "IIS_USERS" user permission are available but the IUSR permission are not there..
Now i have added IUSR and the problem solved now im able to create Folders

Comment: @liam sorry Liam , i tried to search the forum for the question . but my search query didnt yield any relavent result so i created a new question.

Comment: Don't apologise, @Phanindra, we get much worse trust me. This is a duplicate though.